# React Navigation Component on redirect loses data when refreshes

Tags: reactjs

I am using React 16.4.1 and React-Router-Dom 4.3.1. I have built a side bar react component using a web component that you pass the data into the web component and this renders the component.

Here is the side bar component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.mySideBarRef = React.createRef();
      this.menuClick = this.menuClick.bind(this);

      this.state = {
        redirect: false,
        redirectUrl: '/',
        menuData: [
          {
            groupName: 'Group 1',
            icon: 'Home',
            children: [
              {
                title: 'Home',
                icon: 'favorite',
                url: '/',
              },
              {
                title: 'Grp 1 Item 2',
                children: [
                {
                title: 'Roles',
                icon: 'Person',
                url: '/roles',
              },
              {
                title: 'About',
                icon: 'gesture',
                url: '/about',
              },
                  {
                    title: 'Google',
                    icon: 'world',
                    url: 'http://www.google.co.uk',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            groupName: 'Group 2',
            icon: 'search',
            children: [
              {
                title: 'Grp 2 Item 1',
                icon: 'microsoft',
                children: [
                  {
                    title: 'Grp 2 Item 1.1 Bing',
                    icon: '',
                    url: 'http://www.google.co.uk',
                  },
                  {
                    title: 'Grp 2 Item 1.2 Bing',
                    icon: '',
                    url: 'http://www.bing.com',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      let sideMenuContainer = this.mySideBarRef.current;
      sideMenuContainer.sideMenuData = this.state.menuData;
      sideMenuContainer.overrideCustomUrlEvent = true;
      window.addEventListener('customUrlEvent', this.menuClick)
    }

    menuClick(e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.setState({
          redirect: true,
          redirectUrl: e.url
      });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.mySideBarRef.current.removeEventListener('customUrlEvent', this.menuClick);

    }

    render() {
      if(this.state.redirect) {
        this.state.redirect = false;
        return <Redirect to={this.state.redirectUrl} />;
      }


      if(this.state.menuData !== null) {
        return(
          <side-bar-component 
            ref={this.mySideBarRef}
            collapsable>
          </side-bar-component>
        );
      }
    }
  }

export default Sidebar;
```

When the side-bar component loads it renders the data correctly, as soon  as you click on one of the links it does redirect the page but the data does not load, because the componentDidMount does not get triggered. Here is the app.js

```
// This component handles the App template used on every page.
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './common/header';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import HomePage from './home/home-page';
import RolesPage from './role/roles-page';
import AboutPage from './about/about-page';
import { ManageRolePage } from "./role/manage-role-page";
import Sidebar from "./common/sidebar"; //eslint-disable-line import/no-named-as-default

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          loading={this.props.loading}
        />
        <div>
          <div className="demo-sidebar-container">
              <Sidebar />
          </div>
          <div className="demo-content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path="/roles" component={RolesPage}/>
            <Route path="/role/:id" component={ManageRolePage}/>
            <Route path="/role" component={ManageRolePage} exact />
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    loading: state.ajaxCallsInProgress > 0
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Being new to react I think I am missing a fundamental step, what I am trying to achieve is for the redirect to happen and also have the choice depending on business logic to either reload the data into the side menu or to retain the data as the clicked item will be expanded and would like to retain the side menu data. My example above has a hard-coded data-set but eventually I would have a service that would be parameterised. Any guidance or examples on what I am trying to achieve would be grateful.

**

> After reading Adams comments I have made the following changes: I
>   lifted all the code into sidebar-container.js and now my sidebar.js
>   looks like this;

**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const Sidebar = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <dijits-ui-dds-sidebar
      ref={ref}
      collapsable>
    </dijits-ui-dds-sidebar>
));
export default Sidebar;
```

**

> My sidebar-container.js file now consists of all the logic for
>   controlling the side bar:

**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as sideMenuActions from '../../actions/side-bar-actions';
import Sidebar from "./sidebar";
import sideMenu from "../../reducers/side-menu-reducer";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

class SidebarContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.mySideBarRef = React.createRef();
    this.menuClick = this.menuClick.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      redirect: false,
      redirectUrl: '/',
      sideMenu: Object.assign({}, this.props.sideMenu),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sideMenuContainer = this.mySideBarRef.current;
    if(this.state.sideMenu.menuData !== undefined) {
      sideMenuContainer.sideMenuData = this.state.sideMenu.menuData;
    }
    sideMenuContainer.overrideCustomUrlEvent = true;
    window.addEventListener('customUrlEvent', this.menuClick);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.sideMenu !== this.state.sideMenu) {
      let sideMenuContainer = this.mySideBarRef.current;
      if(nextProps.sideMenu.menuData !== undefined) {
         sideMenuContainer.sideMenuData = nextProps.sideMenu.menuData;
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mySideBarRef.current.addEventListener('customUrlEvent', this.menuClick);
  }

  menuClick(e) {
     console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      redirect: true,
      redirectUrl: e.url
    });
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.redirect) {
      this.setState({ redirect: false} );
      return <Redirect to={this.state.redirectUrl} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar sideMenu={this.props.sideMenu} ref={this.mySideBarRef}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SidebarContainer.propTypes = {
  sideMenu: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  debugger;
  return {
    sideMenu: state.sideMenu,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(sideMenuActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (SidebarContainer);
```

**

> And the sidebar containers sit's in my app.js.

**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './common/header';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import HomePage from './home/home-page';
import RolesPage from './role/roles-page';
import AboutPage from './about/about-page';
import { ManageRolePage } from "./role/manage-role-page";
import SidebarContainer from "./common/sidebar-container"; //eslint-disable-line import/no-named-as-default

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          loading={this.props.loading}
        />
        <div>
          <div className="sidebar-container">
              <SidebarContainer sideMenu={this.props.sideMenu} />
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path="/roles" component={RolesPage}/>
            <Route path="/role/:id" component={ManageRolePage}/>
            <Route path="/role" component={ManageRolePage} exact />
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {

  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  sideMenu: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  debugger;
  return {
    loading: state.ajaxCallsInProgress > 0,
    sideMenu: state.sideMenu,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**

> But I am still getting the same issue of when I click on a items on
>   the side menu bar to route me to a different route the bar loses the
>   data. I know the reason why, but trying to find a solution to this.
>   The menuClick(e) function in the container set the redirect property
>   and the redirectUrl state values which refreshes the state and forces
>   the parent container to reload, I also in the render need to set the
>   state of the redirect back to false. Which is causing the parent to
>   refresh being the container and then forcing the sidebar to refresh. I
>   feel I am missing something or misunderstanding something within react
>   way of doing things. Also I have an action that executes to bring the
>   initial load of the side bar and it looks like the componentDidMount
>   was not setting the propType for the child component, so I added the
>   componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method which picked up propType
>   changes. So does this mean that I do not need to have the following
>   line in the componentDidMount method?

**

```
if(this.state.sideMenu.menuData !== undefined) {
  sideMenuContainer.sideMenuData = this.state.sideMenu.menuData;
}
```

**

> Apologise for my slow response, but I look forward for your
>   assistance. Once again thank you community for your support.

**

Also include my routes.js in case this might be needed to help troubleshoot this issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { Route, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/app';
import HomePage from './components/home/home-page';
import AboutPage from './components/about/about-page';
import RolesPage from './components/role/roles-page';
import ManageRolePage from './components/role/manage-role-page'; //eslint-disable-line import/no-named-as-default

export default (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" components={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="roles" component={RolesPage}/>
      <Route path="role" component={ManageRolePage}/>
      <Route path="role/:id" component={ManageRolePage}/>
      <Route path="about" component={AboutPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

After a little more playing I changed the `menuClick` event to use a private variable rather then state variables for redirectUrl or for redirect flag.

```
menuClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.redirectUrl = e.url;
    this.redirect = true;
  }
```

Which means that state is not being updated but I can retain the menu expand but page does not redirect because I am not hitting the render function event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components will re-render whenever their state or props change, meaning their `render` method will run again, and their relevant lifecycle methods.

The thing I notice the most about your code is that you are using the `Route`, but you are not using a `Switch` or `BrowserRouter`. This may be related. I can't tell for sure, but because your `<SideBar>` component is upstream from the Routes, it will simply not re-render or update unless its state or props change.

I would think your sidebar would just not update and the data may load initially but would become stale.

But never fear, allow me to link you an article that I think will bring you to the next level: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf (note to future individuals: if that URL breaks in the future, let me know)

I think you will figure it out after reading that, but it will detail `BrowserRouter`, `Switch`, and `Route`. I think you need to change your code to use all three of those.

Remember that the Sidebar (and all of its children) will only update if it's state or props change.

You could do something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: {},
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar data={this.state.data} />
        <AnotherComponent onEventOccurred={newData => this.setState({ data: newData })} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In React, we call it **lifting state**, so the parent of your Sidebar would be the component that controls the state that the sidebar relies on. Inside the Sidebar, you could refer to that state as `this.props.data` (or if it was a stateless functional component, as `props.data`). The sidebar would re-render itself every time that prop changed.

The second part of that is shown by:

```
<AnotherComponent onEventOccurred={newData => this.setState({ data: newData })} />
```

That component has a prop called `onEventOccurred` which could be called from inside that component as `this.props.onEventOccurred(newData)` or if functional non-class component as `props.onEventOccurred()`. It's literally just a callback, so you call it and it fires `this.setState()` in its parent. It is an extremely powerful pattern because it allows the parent to control what it will do for that event because the action is defined in the parent. The child simply triggers the callback.

I was initially hesitant to post an answer, but I now feel like you might get a lot out of this. Let me know if anything specific is still unclear. I want you to read the whole Medium article I linked first. The pattern shown in it is very common and idiomatic.

I just noticed you have Redux installed. This is a definite increase in complexity overall, but it is good for cross-cutting concerns. Sometimes we call it sideways data loading. Normally, data flows unidirectionally in React, meaning always from parent to child, upstream to downstream.

With Redux, you would call an action creator from any of your components and your Sidebar would be listening to changes on the state Object. Redux is used when you want pieces of state to be shared across multiple components not directly connected to eachother.

With Redux, connected components are listening for changes on the 'basically' global state tree. When the state changes, components that are subscribed will update.

For example in your Sidebar, you could have this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    loading: state.ajaxCallsInProgress > 0,
    data: state.sidebar,
  };
}
```

and it would update its `this.props.data` every time `state.sidebar` changed. I'm trying to keep this as minimal as possible because I may fantastically confuse you with extra info, but that is the most important part. Components using `connect()` are subscribed to changes on the global state tree.

Connect is a higher order component that wraps around the component using it, so when the app's state changes, it causes that component's props to change, which triggers a re-render.

Comment: Hi Adam, Firstly thank you for your response. Your advise is great and thank you. I am trying a few of the approaches you have recommended and will feed back how I was able to achieve this.

Comment: Bobby, I see you edited my answer and it got rejected. Try posting that exact same stuff into your question at the bottom of it. Stack Overflow isn't the best at doing this kind of incremental addon type of stuff. If you lost the changes, I can still see them in the rejected review thing. Let me know, I will review them closer, but the best place to add is in your question like "[edit]: new stuff based on answers below ____".

Comment: Luckily I did not shut my machine down so was able to go into browser history to get this. :)

Comment: Did not exactly solve my problem but pointed me in the right direction.